# windows error 2 occurred while loading the java vm blackberry webworks

Tags: java, cordova, blackberry-webworks

Please how do I solve this problem that I have?

I have been trying to install `BlackBerry WebWorks` but the following error occurred while loading the Java VM:

> windows error 2

I have tried to install 32bit java JDK yet the error still keeps showing.

I have set the environment path, still no positive response.

I need help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the installation file "WebWorks-Tablet-Win-v2.2" that uses intallationAnywhere to deploy itself ran this error at 99% of the installation.
That was because i had multiple JRE installed on my computer for different versions.

First for the installation to work you have to pay attention to the correct Runtime environment required that is mentioned in the system requirement. 
Runtime environment Java® Runtime Environment 1.6
So for me i had to download jre-6u5-windows-i586-p-s from java archive.

Solution is to run the installation from command prompt, with LAX_VM switch, pointing to he Java Dir location.

WebWorks-Tablet-Win-v2.2.exe LAX_VM "Java_DIR/jre/bin/java.exe"

example: WebWorks-Tablet-Win-v2.2.exe LAX_VM C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_73\bin\java.exe